# How can I get a pathname from a groupId?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I encountered a situation requiring to change a `@{groupId}` which is a user property of `maven-deploy-plugin` to a pathname for `maven-antrun-plugin`.

```
<zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${groupId}.zip"
     basedir="${settings.localRepository}"
     includes="${path?/to?/the?groupId?}/**/*"/>
```

How can I get `a/b/c` from a `${groupId}`, say `a.b.c`,

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @khmarbaise https://github.com/jinahya/java-me-sdk-installer/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: You can use maven-assembly-plugin to create such things...

Comment: @khmarbaise Why don't you show me some example, using `maven-assembly-plugin` for archiving all artifacts of a specific `groupId` resides in local repository?